# Why does the roll_out event fire in this code?

Tags: apache-flex

I have made this short example to demonstrate some problems I'm having.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Canvas
        id="buttonCanvas"
        x="100" y="100" opaqueBackground="#000000" width="80%" height="300"
        creationComplete="init(event)">
        <mx:Button x="5" y="5"/>
        <mx:Button x="5" y="50"/>

    </mx:Canvas>


    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init(event:Event):void{
            buttonCanvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function(event:Event):void{
                buttonCanvas.opaqueBackground=(buttonCanvas.opaqueBackground==0)? 0x666666:0;
            });         
        }    
    ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

I don't understand the following:

1. Why don't the percentage or absolute dimensions affect the canvas size?
2. Why does the roll_out event fire when the mouse leaves a button (even when it is still inside the canvas).

I'm going nuts trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to use `backgroundColor` style and not `opaqueBackground` property?

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing at this, I can tell  you that the default value for `opaqueBackground` is **null**, not **0**.

Comment: I have set it to 0 explicitly. It does seem to be 0 when run (the background is black).